# SQL Server Trigger Tables with foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, triggers, identity

I have the following situation (SQL Server Express):

- 2 tables connected via a pk-fk constraint
- a view that joins these two tables
- the program to use the database only has access to the view
- an instead of trigger for inserts on the view

The idea is that the trigger enters data into the 1. table -> a new PK is created via IDENTITY, the second table now has to contain the 1. table's ID as part of it's primary key...

How can I access the newly created PK of the 1. table in a multi-connection-environment? This is a simplified/modifed version of the database:

```
CREATE TABLE Training (  
Training_ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
Name NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Kilometer (
Training_ID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Training(Training_ID),  
Kilometer_ID INT NOT NULL,
Timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Training_ID, Kilometer_ID);

CREATE VIEW TrainingView (  
SELECT t.Name, k.Timestamp
FROM Training t LEFT JOIN Kilometer k ON (t.Training_ID = k.Training_ID));

CREATE TRIGGER TrainingTrigger ON TrainingView INSTEAD OF INSERT AS BEGIN
INSERT INTO Training(Name) SELECT Name FROM inserted;
INSERT INTO Kilometer(Training_ID, Kilometer_ID, Timestamp) SELECT @@Identity, 0, Timestamp FROM inserted;
END;
```

The default '0' for Kilometer_ID is mandatory due to other definitions in the database, merging these two tables is not an option...
While the Trigger seems to function right, I'm not sure if it will in a multi-user environment (what happens to @@Identity, if another connection alters the table?)

Is there a better solution to this trigger?

Greetz Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your concern with @@Identity is the only issue use SCOPE_IDENTITY() , which returns the most recently created id FROM THE SAME SCOPE.

Differences explained here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: Thanks for the link, do you have any other concern with the design?

Comment: I might've just stored a procedure for the two inserts instead, but your trigger looks sound.  I'm not sure if i really get what the table is about, but structure looks ok as long as you dont mind that you cant insert multiple rows in one statement as Matt explains.

Comment: ok, i might have oversimplified the example code, inserting multiple rows in one statement is not really needed currently (at least according to the current requirement :) )

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is probably going to work pretty much all the time if it's in a low volume environment of single inserts.  In SQL Server, if you use SCOPE_IDENTITY is better because it only gets identities from the current scope.

If you want to insert multiple rows into this view at once (e.g., `insert into TrainingView select ...`) this is going to break because you'll need more than one TrainingID.  For this, you can use [SQL Server's OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to get your all your IDs for that insert.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll better update to SCOPE_IDENTITY. If I understand it correctly that function will return the last identity the trigger created no matter how often the trigger is executed in parallel or where else in the database a identity is updated. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. SCOPE_IDENTITY() will return the last identity your specific routine in your specific session inserts, regardless of what else is going on in the DB or how long it takes you to call SCOPE_IDENTITY.  So, if you insert but leave your window/connection open, someone else inserts, then you get around to calling SCOPE_IDENTITY(), you get your last-inserted ID and not theirs.